# Changing IBOutlet UIObject in ViewController from another class using Objective C (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm a beginner in iOS development and cannot get this part working. The objective is simple: I have a class named `TCPComm` which connects to a server and sends data periodically. In my Storyboard I have a view containing some buttons and a textfield. The idea is to change the state of the `IBOutlet` `UIButtons` and `UITextField` based on the received data from the server (from another class).

I have tried using properties in different ways but none of them worked.

Any help on the best way to do this please?

Comment: can you please show code?

Comment: An IBOutlet refers to special ivar or property referenced in Xcode Interface Builder. You’ll need to set the IBOutlet before it can be updated. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/AboutInterfaceBuilder.html. You’ll also want to set an IBAction to have the user trigger the change in state.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is using Delegates.

In your TCPComm header file declare protocol

```
@protocol tcpCommDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)callBackMethod;
@end
```

In the interface declare a public property

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<tcpCommDelegate> delegate;
```

Now, call the method declared in protocol whenever you received some data in your TCPComm class like below

```
if(delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callBackMethod)])
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(callBackMethod)];
```

Now, in your viewcontroller class make sure you imported TCPComm class and it accepts the tcpCommDelegate protocol like below

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <tcpCommDelegate>
```

In viewDidLoad method of ViewController create an instance of TCPComm class and assign its delegate property to self

```
TCPComm *tcpcomm = [[TCPComm alloc]init];
tcpcomm.delegate = self;
```

That's, it now you can implement the callBackMethod body in your viewcontroller and change the properties of whatever UIObjects you want. This method will be called whenever there is new data fetched by your TCPComm class, if you have called the 3rd code snippet at the right time i.e when data fetch completed

Comment: Thanks Harsha will try it out! Is there any advantage of using this method over using Notifications? I've managed to implement something similar using notifications which basically calls a defined method whenever the notification is received...worked well but not sure which is the most appropriate way of doing it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using Notifications as that is easier to code and multiple objects can subscribe to that notification, which is an advantage over delegates. On the other side Delegation is a good programming practise and learning to use delegates makes your coding lot more smoother as you go on. If you are comfortable with Notifications then you can use them, its you who need to decide which one to use based on your requirements.